# Move <li> elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can i change the markup below?

So this markup:

```
<ul>
   <li class="step">Step</li>
   <li class="form-group">1</li>
   <li class="form-group">2</li>
   <li class="form-group">3</li>
   <li class="step">Step</li>
   <li class="form-group">4</li>
   <li class="form-group">5</li>
</ul>
```

Would become this markup:

```
<ul>
   <li class="step">Step
      <ul>
         <li class="form-group">1</li>
         <li class="form-group">2</li>
         <li class="form-group">3</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="step">Step
      <ul>
         <li class="form-group">4</li>
         <li class="form-group">5</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I am starting with something like this but I'm stumped

```
$("ul")
.find("li.step")
.append("<ul class='step-container'></ul>")
.end()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nextUntil() will job the job for you

```js
// find all the steps
$("li.step").each( function () {
  var li = $(this)
  // create a new ul
  var newUL = $("<ul></ul>")
  // grab the siblings until you hit the next step
  // and append them to the ul
  newUL.append(li.nextUntil("li.step"))
  // add the ul to the step
  li.append(newUL)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li class="step">Step</li>
   <li class="form-group">1</li>
   <li class="form-group">2</li>
   <li class="form-group">3</li>
   <li class="step">Step</li>
   <li class="form-group">4</li>
   <li class="form-group">5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
const $steps = $("ul#t").children("li.step").toArray().map(function(s) { return $(s); });
for (let $step of $steps) {
    const $next = $step.nextUntil("li.step");
    const $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
    $ul.append($next);
    $ul.appendTo($step);
}
```

Also make sure that the `ul` can be uniquely identified, like `ul#exampleId`, because like this you would also target other `ul`s.

Comment: Close, but this generates invalid HTML. `<ul>
   <li class="step">Step</li><ul><li class="form-group">1</li><li class="form-group">2</li><li class="form-group">3</li></ul>
   
   
   
   <li class="step">Step</li><ul><li class="form-group">4</li><li class="form-group">5</li></ul>
   
   
</ul>`

Comment: Fixed, check it now.